# Unable to mount/access phone after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade, mtp, nokia, windows-phone

A Nokia Lumia 920 will not mount in 14.04. When I was running 13.10 this wasn't an issue. What should I try? Or will I have to revert to 13.10?

What mtp-detect shows:

```
kjhg@kjhg-LIFEBOOK-AH530-HD6:~$ mtp-detect
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.libmtp version: 1.1.6

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=0421 and PID=0661) is a Nokia Nokia Lumia WP8.
   Found 1 device(s):
   Nokia: Nokia Lumia WP8 (0421:0661) @ bus 2, dev 4
Attempting to connect device(s)
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

Comment: An update today seems to have fixed this. I don't know which. I didn't see anything obviously related to mtp in the updates

Comment: ... And after Monday's updates, it's not mounting again.

Comment: same problem with galaxy s3 on lubuntu 14.04

Comment: Does this SO question help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/463015/ubuntu-14-04-and-android-cant-see-phone-on-my-computer

Comment: It's a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1314556

Answer (score 1):

Problems like this happen a lot during an upgrade. I recommend that you simply install 14.04 over your existing setup. You'll want to backup your /home directory but most installs will save that.
The reason this happens IMHO is when the config files are updating they don't always update correctly. I've actually seen Linuxes where this is a listed "upgrade method".

Answer (score 1):

Installing mtp-tools and/or mtpfs has solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

You may need to reboot to get it work completely.

Comment: I'm getting "Unable to locate package mtpfs". Is it deprecated or something. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @NikhilWagh has your problem been resolved? I'm having the same one..

Comment: @Mihail can you test if it works without mtpfs, only installing mtp-tools, and rebooting? `sudo apt install mtp-tools`

Comment: @Mihail No it wasn't I just changed my OS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an HTC One S (on Linux Mint 17 and Ubuntu 14.04). It was a bit weird because till this morning, I was able to deploy apps on the device using Eclipse, but this morning, the device started to refuse being recognized.

I tried to connect a Nexus 5 and it mounted fine while the same error still persisted. I could access the device's storage from Ubuntu without any problem. So I realized **the problem was with the phone**, rather than Ubuntu/Mint. Then I **reset the other device (HTC) to the factory settings**, and now it works fine, although when I connect the cable, Ubuntu still shows an error ("Unable to open MTP device '[usb:x,x]'"), but I can safely ignore the error since I can access the device's internal storage using the default file managers (Nemo and Nautilus) and of course the device gets recognized in the ADB. Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while upgrading from linux mint 16 to linux mint 17.

My nexus 5 mounted correctly while I was in mint 16 but when the system was upgraded to mint 17 the device no longer mounted, however i was able to access it through a windows virtual machine so the problem wasn't critical.

Later I did a clean install of mint 17 and the phone mounted correctly again with no issues until today.