# I can't open any file from my (Samsung) S3 Mini on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, 14.04, samsung, mtp

I hate the way Samsung uses to transfer files, I wonder if there is a driver or something i can install to fix this problem because I downloaded a driver on Windows in order to use my s3 mini, I am new in Ubuntu so please someone help me please. OK this is the problem... I connect my phone, ubuntu mounts it but i can't open any file, only copy or move them. I want to open them directly instead of moving the file to the Pc... please help me...

Comment: What version of Android is on the **S3 Mini** (i819x)? I was having no issues with **MTP** (with my S3 Mini), but have since switched to the (newer) **S4 Mini** (i9197).

Comment: I have issues with S3 Mini(GT-I8190L) Android 4.1.2, Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 (SM-T211) Android 4.1.2, but I don't have issues with my tablet lenovo ideapad a1000-f Android 4.1.2 and my Galaxy Ace Android 2.3.6 because they uses the traditional mass storage way...

Comment: The problem is **MTP** (under Android **4.1.x**). I upgraded to my S4 Mini (i9197, **4.2.2**) because it is due for *KitKat* (**4.4.2**) soon. But my S3 Mini (i8190, **4.1.2**) worked OK with MTP. However, I had major MTP issues with the *Tab2 7.0* (P3110) *until* I upgraded to **4.2.2**. *Not sure what to recommend.*

Comment: Possible dupe [Unable to mount/access phone after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/455412/unable-to-mount-access-phone-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem after upgrading to 14.04.

Under 13.10 I got the Samsung tablet set up to do its usb as a camera. You need to get into the usb menu on the tablet (which only shows when the usb is connected!) There is a usb symbol at the top of the screen.

This didn't work after upgrading to 14.04. So....I set the tablet usb to MTP and ...

I installed `mtp-tools` and `mtpfs` like this from the command line.

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

That did not work straight away. Then I installed `gMTP`. `gMTP` did not work.

But after running `gMTP` and closing and opening `Nautilus` (the file manager), `Nautilus` started to see both my Samsung tablet and the SD card on it. I can transfer files normally.

Comment: 1 up for gMTP!!

Answer (score 0):

Last time I was trying to connect my Note 2, I experienced similar issues - previous versions of Android would just mount as an external drive etc. The change to the supported protocols was a Google/Android thing, not Samsung.

I tried some of the things mentioned above, but with only very limited success - I ended up using "Airdroid" to do the transfers of music etc wirelessly, as it was just too much faffing about to sort the wired connection.......