# Connect Android phone with Ubuntu PC through USB

Tags: usb

I am using infocus m2. I want to transfer some videos from my mobile to my PC.

I am using Ubuntu on my PC. When I connect my mobile to my PC via the USB port the the mobile storage is not shown by Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you keep your phone in camera mode...ie..Connected as a Camera..

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/463015/ubuntu-14-04-and-android-cant-see-phone-on-my-computer

Comment: [Enabling USB debugging](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) always work.

Comment: @reversiblean adb is unrelated to accessing files on the phone unless you have to use `adb pull/push`

Answer (score 2):

Many new phones allow access through MTP at best and it might be set to something else by default. So first on your phone look in "settings" for something like "PC connection" and make sure it is on "storage" or "media transfer". If you have a usb storage option we're done here.

Otherwise I think MTP support is provided to Gnome/Nautilus by the "gvfs-backends" package, to install try:

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends
```

Then it should just show up as a disk (phone must be *unlocked* to initially access). Ok were done now right?

...

As a last resort "adb" can do file transfers. Enable/enter developer options and turn on usb-debugging. Install adb:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

Then the command will be something like (warning: be in the directory you want the files in):

```
adb pull <path/to/your/file>
```

Where  will be something like "/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/", but this will probably be device specific (pro-tip: you can use "adb shell" to stumble around and find the DCIM directory).

Best of luck.