# Oneplus X - Android 6.0 won't mount

Tags: 16.04, usb, mount, android

Heres the deal, before i upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 (and from 5.1 to 6.0.1, yes i did it at the same time, stupid me) everything worked just fine. Then i upgraded, and i got a bunch on error messages about mounting issues. So i restarted the PC, and now the phone wont even attempt to mount.

```
Ubuntu version: 16.04 
Android version: 6.0.1 
Phone: One plus X 
USB debugging: ON 
USB Configuration: MTP
```

The goal is to debug android studio *(v2.2.2)* apps on the phone.

I have tried installing `mtpfs` acording to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/463921/599392) post. But it didn't seem to make a difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Update 1:** 
I just tried to connect with my Samsung 7, and it works right of the bat. 
Still no progress on the one plus though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out oneplus screwed up their connection-options, you have to be fast. When connecting the connection-option-notification shows up in the notification bar, but only for a second or two. You have to press it, and make sure the connection mode is set to MTP. (even though the USB configuration was set to MTP, this has to be done either way.)

Comment: IDK If 1+ screwed it up or not. I have a moto G phone and since a random update (3rd party rom) I have to pull down notifications and change the USB mode from `charging` to `file transfers`. As the situations are similar, it could well be an Android issue but I can't say for sure either way..